# Google Datastore client query similar to SQL union or In-clause

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm exploring ways (Since I'm new to google datastore) to achieve bulk request similar to what we do using SQL `IN-Clause` or `Union`.

What I currently have (below) is very inefficient way of executing query per item in for loop. Any help is much appreciated.

I need to do this in Flex-Environment, means i cannot use `ndb` here.

**Sample code:**

```
result_list = []

for name in person_names:
   client = datastore.Client()
   query = client.query(kind='Person')
   query.add_filter('name', '=', name)
   result = list(query.fetch(1))
   if len(result) == 1:
      result_list.append(result[0])
```